# Function with parameters React-Native

Tags: parameter-passing, react-native

I have this function

```
export default async function get_happy_songs(param) {

    let emotion = param;
    // console.log(emotion)
    ...

    }
```

and at some point I want to do this :

```
let arg = value;
let happy_songs =  await get_happy_songs(arg);
```

But I know that it is something wrong with the function definition syntax, so what I should do to my function to be able to get that argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it i hope you will found useful

```
export async function get_happy_songs(param) {
let emotion = param;
console.log(emotion)
return true
}




 async componentDidMount() {
 
    let happy_songs =  await get_happy_songs('Love you like  you do');
    console.log(happy_songs)
}
```